# Updating a list of map in Dynamo DB using Boto3 with Python

Tags: python, amazon-dynamodb, boto3

I have a response from my Dynamo DB as:

```
{
'subject': 'Mathematics', 
'course_id': '123', 
'Term': 'Second', 
'stats': 
              {'student_stats': 
                            [
                             {'student_id': '234', 
                              'registration_id': '321'}, 
                             {'student_id': '987', 
                             'registration_id': '456'}
                             ]
              }, 
}
```

Where the partition key is 'subject' and the sort key is 'course_id'.

I would like to update the 'student_stats' for student with 'student_id' as '234' to passed.

The output should look like this:

```
{
'subject': 'Mathematics', 
'course_id': '123', 
'Term': 'Second', 
'stats': 
              {'student_stats': 
                            [
                             {'student_id': '234', 
                              'registration_id': '321',
                              'status: 'passed'}, 
                             {'student_id': '987', 
                             'registration_id': '456'}
                             ]
              }, 
}
```

This is my implementation so far:

```
dynamodb = boto3.resource(
        'dynamodb',
        aws_access_key_id=ACCESS_KEY,
        aws_secret_access_key=ACCESS_SECRET
    )
table = dynamodb.Table(TABLE_NAME)

response = table.update_item(Key={'subject': 'Mathematics',
                                  'course_id': '123'},
                             UpdateExpression="set #status=:s",
                             ExpressionAttributeNames={
                                 '#status': 'stats.student_stats'
                             },
                             ExpressionAttributeValues={
                                 ':s': 'passed'
                             },
                             ReturnValues="UPDATED_NEW"
                             )
```

Comment: You can only update arrays by specifying the position not by specifying anything within the value.